# Powershell - использование кириллицы

Tags: powershell, кириллица

День добрый.
Выполняю запрос к API, и получаю результат в формате JSON, с которым в дальнейшем предстоит работать.
Однако при попытке вывести результат в консоли - вместо кириллицы выводятся кракозябры.

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")
$Url = $MyServer;
   $resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8";
   if ($resp.success) 
   { 
      foreach ($item in $resp.mails) 
      {
         Write-Host $item.body;
      }
   }
```

В результате, в `$item.body` я получаю : `ÐšÐ¸Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð»Ð¸Ñ†Ð°`
Каким образом заставить `powershell` работать с uft-8?

Answer (score 1):

Наличие повторяющегося символа **Ð** в выводе символов в UTF-8 кодировке свидетельствует, что консоль продолжает использовать Win-1251.

Попробуйте первую строчку заменить на:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
```